# String.Split is not behaving as expected

Tags: java, string, split

I have a very large String. It can be seen here: 
http://pastebin.com/vqXJ3WV6

I want to split this string using the regex 3.8 
When I search this string using notepad, I find two instances of 3.8. 
Therefore, I would expect the array which is returned to have a length of 3.

```
System.err.println(convertPdfToText(save).split("3.8").length);
```

However, calling this with convertPdfToText fetching this String has a length of 4?

[image]

I do not understand this at all in the slightest. Can anybody tell me what is going on because this is changing the behaviour of my program massively.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `3.8` interpreted as a regex means `3<whatever char>8`. Is it your intended behavior?

Comment: No it is not. I mean the number 3.8

Comment: Your regex should looks like "3\\.8"

Comment: Next tipp, do not write the code in one line. you cannot debug that; write String str = convertPdfTotext(save); String[] parts = str.split("3.8"); System.err.println("length = " + parts.length);

Comment: can you tell what is the big idea behind? What do you want to separate: maybe the regex is the wrong approach

Comment: I need to extract the vocab in the vocabulary section which has the heading of 3.8

Comment: ok i deleetd my answer, my fault. split() needs an regex, while i thought it takes an ordinary substring; Unfortunately "." is a special regex character, which has to be escaped to get a normal "."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` character is a special character in regex which literally means "any character". So you're basically looking for `3[anything]8`, and a quick regex search shows that there is indeed 3 matches for that. Two are the valid "3.8" strings you were actually looking for. Your unintended match is located at the end of this string:

```
3.4 Unit 3: Spanish speaking 46953 8
```

The solution is simply to use the `.` literal instead by escaping the character with backslashes:

```
System.err.println(convertPdfToText(save).split("3\\.8").length);
```